# How to set print page formatting is different than screen page?

Tags: printing, stylesheet, media

I have a screen page which contains tables and special formatting. I want to set different formatting such as column width, height etc. for print page and screen page.

How should I set different formatting for screen and print page?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `print` media type to specify a print-specific stylesheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print" />
```

Alternatively, you can add the print stylesheet inline using `@media`:

```
@media print {
    .title-column { width: 300px; }

}
```

[According to this source](http://www.codestyle.org/css/media/projection-BrowserSummary.shtml), browser support should not be a problem.